# Asset Swap Process Changed?

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

Has anyone noticed that in the newest UXSDK 4.7 the “Assets” folder is seemingly missing and now only the .car file is there? This seemingly makes it harder to do an Asset swap as highlighted in the DJI documentation. Was this intentional? Does anyone have a workaround to continue to asset swap widgets

Asset Swap Procedure
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/ux_sdk_introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

In 4.7 we switched to be using Asset Catalog. Your observation is correct. Developers won't be able to swap assets the way they would with Asset folders anymore.
We are working on a short tutorial/shell script to handle such task with Asset Catalog and will upload that on our GitHub repo next week.
Stay tuned.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to the new process.

Comment: Is there an update to this? Is there a short tutorial/shell script to handle such a task with Asset Catalog?